# how to include helpers in jsreport

Tags: javascript, .net-core, handlebars.js, jsreport

I am using Dotnet Core 2.2 to generate report with JSReport (https://jsreport.net/)
I use local JsReport so I sent my template and data to the local server and get back the pdf. Now I need to format date in javascript, so I require to include moment.js into my templates. I have no idea how to do that.

In html I  need to format StartDate to formated Date using moment.js 
I have no idea how to include moment.js into template and how to add helpers.

For JSReport I am using engine chrome-pdf and handlebars as templating engine (https://jsreport.net/learn/handlebars)

I have tried to include moment.js in the

```
<script src="http://localhost:5000/public/js/moment.js"/>
<script>
function formatDate(date){
return moment(date).format("dd MMMM yyyy");
}
</script>
```

but when I called **{{{formateDate startDate}}}}** inside the html template, it seems the function/helpers not recognized.

My C# code:

```
[HttpGet("reporting")]
    public async  Task<IActionResult> Test(){
        var sdr = await _repo.GetStaffDefaultRates();  
        var dto  = _mapper.Map<List<StaffDefaultRate>, List<ReportDto>>(sdr);          
        var x = new {
            bootstrapcss = "http://localhost:5000/public/css/bootstrap.min.css",
            publicPath = "http://localhost:5000/public/",
            message = "hello world",
            today = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"),
            staffRates = dto,
        };
        var staffRates = _fileRepository.ReadReportTemplate("StaffRates.html");
        var rs = new ReportingService("http://localhost:5488");
        var report = await rs.RenderAsync(new RenderRequest(){
            Template = new Template(){
                Recipe = Recipe.ChromePdf,
                Engine = Engine.Handlebars,
                Content = staffRates,
            }, Data = x 
        }); 
        var memory = new MemoryStream();
        await report.Content.CopyToAsync(memory);
        memory.Position = 0 ;
        return File(memory, "application/pdf");
        // return Ok(staffRates);
    }
```

My templates:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title> Staff Default Rates</title>
    <link href="{{bootstrapcss}}" rel="stylesheet">
    </link>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="sticky-top">
        <div class="row pt-3 header">
            <div class="col-6 text-left">
                <img src="http://localhost:5000/public/logo-full.jpg" width="100%"></img>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6 text-right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-5">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <h2>Staff List {{today}}</h2>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th rowspan="2">&nbsp;</th>
                            <th rowspan="2" colspan="1" class="align-middle">Staff Roles</th>
                            <th > Start Date </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {{#each staffRates}}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{id}}</td>
                            <td>{{staffType}}</td>
                            <td class='text-center'>{{startDate}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {{/each}}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row pb-3 footer fixed-bottom">
            <div class="col-12 text-center">
                <img src="http://localhost:5000/public/footer.jpg" width="100%"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The minimal example would look like this.

```cs
var result = rs.RenderAsync(new RenderRequest  {
    Template = new Template
    {
        Content = "{{myFormat date}}",
        Helpers = @"
const moment = require('moment')
function myFormat(d) { 
  return moment(d).format('dd MMMM yyyy')
}",
        Engine = Engine.Handlebars,
        Recipe = Recipe.ChromePdf
    },
    Data = new
    {
        date = DateTime.Now
    }
}).Result;

result.Content.CopyTo(File.OpenWrite("report.pdf"));
```

Note your server should have [local files access enabled](https://jsreport.net/learn/configuration#allow-local-files-and-local-modules). Otherwise the call `require('moment')` throws. The provided example will work as it is on default jsreport because it has moment module already installed. In case you want to use another custom module you need to install it using `npm i mycustommodule`.